# Алгоритм поиска m наибольших элементов списка из списка длиной n элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Я примерно понимаю как это можно сделать с помощью quicksort, но там деградировать до квадрата может и реализовывать самому не хочется, есть ли какая-то адекватная реализация на Python'е 3.x? Если знаете, то можно и просто алгоритм.

Буду рад любым подсказкам, спасибо.

Comment: `sort` в Python должен работать за `O(n*log(n))` в худшем случае. В чем проблема? Если нужно самому реализовать, то смотрите [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) и [Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: Дык если у меня список длины n, а я хочу найти m наибольших элементов, причем m сильно меньше n, то у меня сложность nlogm вместо nlogn, что критично.

Comment: [heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html)

Comment: Спасибо!.......

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, причем тут "деградировать  до квадрата"?

Поиск - это не сортировка. В худшем случае у вас будет O(n*m). m проходов по списку из m элементов, с поиском максимального на каждом проходе и его удаления (отметки) из исходного списка.

При условии, что m<<n -  скорость вполне приемлема, особенно при малых m.

Можно еще поиграться с одновременным поиском m максимумов за один проход, но там надо будет дополнительно держать список текущих отобранных. Теоретическая сложность должна бы снизиться, но практическая -  либо из-за динамических списков на Python, либо из-за необходимости сдвига массива на С++ - может и не (сильно) улучшиться.

Comment: Под квадратом я имел в виду жаргон O(mn)

Comment: Тогда причем тут деградировать? Квадратом оно конечно может стать, но только если n=m.  А в реальных ситуация -  O(mn) << O(nlog(n))